# Disappear background in HTML Field

Tags: spfield, image

I created HTML field in SharePoint 2010

```
<Field ID="{3E83492C-0420-473E-AB65-E4355535AFD0}" Name="MyField" StaticName="MyField" DisplayName="My Field" Type="HTML" Required="FALSE"  RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" >
<Default>
  <![CDATA[<div style="background-image:url('http://mytest.com/image.jpg');"><h1>Sample title<h1> <p>sample text</p></div>]]>
</Default>
```

But when I adding new item to list with this field I don't see background.

When I adding this value manually to field I see image, but if I click Save and open again this field, then this image disappear.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I added image in html not as a background then it works

```
<div class="grid_6"> 
    <p>
        <a href="#"> 
            <img src="http://mytest.com/image.jpg'"/>
        </a> 
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is you can add a separate script editor web part on your page and add your styles there.